# Navigate to a Website using the Jetpack Navigation in Menu Drawer

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: Navigate to Website]

I am currently using the Jetpack Navigation, but I can't figure how to navigate to a website URI for example www.google.com on clicking the Calificar item in the menu.

```
    //Toolbar for the Drawer
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    //Drawer Layout
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)

    //Controller for the Navigation
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_random,
            R.id.nav_baloto,
            R.id.nav_revancha,
            R.id.nav_results,
            R.id.nav_yournumbers,
            R.id.nav_about,
            R.id.nav_rate
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

The navigation to the fragments is working fine but can't figure how to navigate to an action, that would be the nav_rate that should open a website.

Comment: This breack the back button from the navigation controller.

Comment: Yeah, it's wrong. Let me post the right one.

Comment: Use this `val navigationItemSelectListener = NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
   handelItemClicked(menuItem)
   false
  }`

Answer (score 0):

After using [OhhhThatVarun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7436566/ohhhthatvarun) solution I was able to partially do the Job, but this is the way I finally solved it, since the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener breack part of the new Jetpack Navigation

In the constructor I added this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

After that I had to create a new Function fot the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_rate -> {
                val rate = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companyname.balotorandom"))
                startActivity(rate)
            }
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

And basically change the way the controller was working
This is the new code:

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_random,
                R.id.nav_baloto,
                R.id.nav_revancha,
                R.id.nav_results,
                R.id.nav_yournumbers,
                R.id.nav_about
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```